# If exists statement in SQL timing out

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

```
If exists 
(
 select 1 from table A join table B
 on A.id = B.id
)
BEgin  
  Select 'Pass'
END
  Select 'Fail'
```

I am confused with the above query which is not executing at all until it gets timed out when it is wrapped in **If exists** statement.

When the statement

```
 select 1 from table A join table B
 on A.id = B.id
```

is executed, it takes 20 secs to give the result but when wrapped it in **If exists** statement, it is not executing at all and finally after 4 -5 hrs I had to cancel it.
What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Is your actual query a two table join or is it more complex? What size are the tables involved? Probably different execution plans anyway. `EXISTS` will favour a plan with non blocking operators such as nested loops.

Comment: Actually it involves three tables i.e., table A left join (select * from table B join table C on condition where B.ColumnA in (select columnX from table D)).............Will the complexity of the query create any problem?

Comment: If you compare the estimated execution plans for both do they have different join orders or join types?

Comment: I cannot find the execution plan for the query which has 'If exists' because the query doesn't complete at all and I always have to stop the execution

Comment: That's why I suggested estimated plans rather than actual. Assuming you are running this in SSMS then click the estimated query plans on the query menu. This doesn't actually execute the query. It just shows you the plans.

Comment: Yes ,the execution plans are different for both...

Comment: @user1400915 ok they are different. What about *showing* them to us? This question cannot be answered without more information. We know almost nothing at the moment.

Comment: Is it possible to paste the .jpg file here because I have captured the execution plan in 2 .jpg files

Comment: Yes. There is an upload image facility available in the toolbar when you edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you studied the execution plan?
I suspect the performance issue is deeper down than the final use of exists and it would help if the full query was available - or at least a full representation of its structure. In a comment you indicate this more elaborate structure:

```
SELECT
        1
FROM table_A AS a
LEFT JOIN (                    -- << why a left join, is it achieving anything?
                SELECT
                        *            -- << not literally select * I hope
                FROM table_B AS b
                JOIN table_C AS c
                             ON b.thing = c.thing
                WHERE B.ColumnA IN (                -- << avoid this type of IN()
                                        SELECT      -- >> if this result is big
                                        columnX
                                        FROM table_D AS d
                                        )
                           ) AS x
                             ON a.thing = x.thing
;
```

At the outer query you are (or at least indicating) only doing 'select 1' so no extraneous fields need be selected in nested subqueries.

You indicate the use of a left join, but so little is known about the details that I can't tell if it's needed or not.

Possibly the most obvious place to look for improvement would be use of IN( subquery here )
if that subquery is producing a substantial number of rows performance will degrade. Either a join or the use of EXISTS is likely be a better choice for this.

EDIT:
with respect to getting an execution plan, consider running each subquery independently starting with the inner most nesting:

```
                                    SELECT      -- >> if this result is big
                                    columnX
                                    FROM table_D AS d
```

Is it using indexes, how many rows are returned (perhaps just do a count(*) for that)

Work up from there to the next subquery, and consider alternatives. e.g. this might work:

```
            SELECT
                    thing  -- << only that which is needed
            FROM table_B AS b
            JOIN table_C AS c
                         ON b.thing = c.thing
            JOIN (
                    SELECT distinct -- >> not a fan of distinct but might help here
                    columnX
                    FROM table_D
                 ) AS D
                   ON B.ColumnA = D.columnX
```

What does the execution plan of this piece tell you?

Working up like this should aid the overall optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Try out Using top 1 like,

```
select top 1 1 from table A join table B  on A.id = B.id
```

This may reduce your time.

Comment: The query will already return the least possible information needed to evaluate the exists. Adding a top 1 adds nothing to the query.